# What is the difference between "we know of no X" vs. "we don't know any X", if any?

Tags: negation

Example:

- We know of no civilian casualties (from [the Hill](https://thehill.com/policy/national-security/569824-embassy-warns-americans-at-kabul-airport-gates-to-leave-immediately?amp))
- We don't know any civilian casualties

Comment: to know of something is formal, written English.

Answer (score 1):

In your example:

> We **know of** no civilian casualties.

"know of" here means "knowledge" or "awareness". The reporter wasn't aware of any casualties.

> We don't **know** any civilian casualties.

In this pattern, "know" means "acquaintance", but as written in your second example that wouldn't be implied (unless you personally were acquainted with them). If you were, it would be better to write it as:

> We don't know **any of** the civilian casualties.

Answer (score 1):

To add information to and perhaps clarify user3196's answer:

These two sentences mean the same thing:

> We know of no civilian casualties

> We don't know of any civilian casualties.

The two sentences above mean that there may or may not be civilian casualties, but we haven't learned about them yet if there are. The first sentence sounds a bit more like we don't expect to learn of any civilian casualties because we think there aren't any.

However this sentence means something different:

> We don't know any of the civilian casualties

It means that there definitely are civilian casualties, but all of those casualties are people we don't know (i.e. we haven't met them; they are strangers).